# Selecting a version when creating a new topic doesn't update the live preview

Tags: feature-request, documentation

I [brought this up](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/31848648#31848648) in the Documentation chat and Jon [suggested](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/31848719#31848719) it was worth putting on meta:

> Is there a reason when creating a new topic, "All Versions" doesn't change despite selecting specific versions? The topic title is <strike>a joke</strike> serious.
>
> [image]

Since the title updates as you type, shouldn't also the version change when you select the versions?

Note: Only the live preview is not updating

Comment: Not just creating. Changing versions while editing doesn't update live preview either.